# Wierd C# exception behaviour: exception not caught in special circumstances

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, exception

I'm programming a dll as extension for a program (Windows 10, Visual Studio Professional 2019). In this dll I have a very weird behaviour. The scenario:
From then 'main' module of the dll (where the callbacks for the application are located) I open a dialog window (own module) which is calling functions in a third module in it's 'Form Shown' event. In this third module I throw an exception (because the user cancelled an action) which I want to catch in the 'main' module.

When I run this dll in VisualStudio debugger (either Debug or Release Configuration, no difference), the Application is started, the dll is loaded and the process described above works like a charm.
When I run the application w/o VisualStudio, the Application is started, the dll is loaded but after throwing the exception it's not caught as before and I get told by the system that an exception was thrown and not caught.

So why does the code work in the IDE environment but not 'standalone'?

The only thing I could imagine was that there are differences in the event handling code of .NET. In the call stack when I stop in the 'Shown' event function, I see that there are calls to "mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext". Is it possible that outside of VS the dll is in another execution context so that the exception is mislead?

I would appreciate if someone could explain me this behaviour. Again, it's not a matter of debug or release version, it's about the execution environment.

Thanks in advance,

Jörg

**EDIT**

I hope this clears the scenario:

dll.cs:

```
// This function is called from the host application
void callback()
{
    try
    {
        Form dialog = new Form();
        dialog.ShowDialog();
    }
    catch (ExceptionType1)
    {
        ...
    }
    catch (ExceptionType2)
    {
        ...
    }
    catch
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

dialog.cs

```
...
// event function for the 'shown' event of Form class
private void SynchronizationDialog_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HelperFunction();
}
...
```

helper.cs

```
// here the exception is thrown
void HelperFunction()
{
    ...
    if(...)
    {
        throw new ExceptionType1();
    }
    ...
}
```

When debugging the dll in VS, the exception thrown in helper.cs is caught by the catch block, which is as expected.
When running the application calling the dll standalone, the exception is not caught.

**EDIT**

I now can provide an example project (VS2020): [ExceptionCatchTest](https://jvnet-oc.spdns.de/index.php/s/NkAWVLW64SqctTp)

If you run it in VS, Exception got caught, else not.

Comment: It would be much more helpful to actually see your code. Where is your try-catch block? Form_Shown event is fired through windows messages and thus an exception thrown in this event will not necessarily be caught by a try-catch around a constructor/show.

Comment: unfortunately I can't post helpful code here because it's not my property, sorry.
You write: "will not necessarily be caught". Can you explain that? Or give me a hint where to look for?

Comment: Forms use windows messages to fire events such as form Load, Shown, MouseMove, Closing, and Closed. My guess is while you are in debug mode, visual studio handles these messages and encapsulates them, enabling you to catch exceptions in your main code. This encapsulation is removed when you compile and thus the try-catch is no longer around the triggering exception. If you could move your exception from the form shown event to the form constructor (not the form load event), then you could catch the exception by putting a try-catch around your `Form form = new Form()` creation of the form.

Comment: @jokey You don't need to upload the source code. Just provide a simple demo that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Adam: I think I didn't describe the scenario clearly. I made a new post with sample code. But in principle I think you're right.
In my project I solved the situation by moving the try-catch-blocks into the form module (into the event function). So it has to do something with differenced in the event handling between VS and standalone apps.
So we have an educated guess but I hoped to find someone who can explain the background.

Comment: @KyleWang: Did it. Thi is only sample code but I think with little changes the code should be compilable and show the behaviour.

Comment: @Panagiotis: Thanks for moving the post content to the original post. I'm not very used yet to post here an just forgot the possibility to edit my post.
I removed the errorneous post. Χαιρετίσματα

Comment: could you please upload your code to some git? I don't like to download random stuffs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a test project using your code and was able to reproduce your problem. Looking through the exception's stack trace it seems the windows message processor [Control.WndProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc?view=netcore-3.1) for the form is only in the stack while running from visual studio. As a test, I overrode the WndProc method in the form to add a try-catch block around the call to the base method

```
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            try
            {
                base.WndProc(ref m);
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("WndProc caught");
                throw;
            }
        }
```

when running from Visual Studio, a message box appears indicating "WndProc caught". When not running in Visual Studio, this message never appears before the program crashes.

Thinking about it, probably the best solution to your problem would be to instead add a publicly visible enumeration such as `public ErrorStatus errorStatus = ErrorStatus.NoError;`. Then, instead of throwing and exception, you could use the following code

```
errorStatus = ErrorStatus.Error1;
DialogResult = DialogResult.Abort;
return;
```

You could then change your calling function to

```
void callback()
{
    using (Form dialog = new Form())
    {
        DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.Abort)
        {
            switch (dialog.errorStatus)
            {
                case ErrorStatus.Error1:
                    ...
                    break;
                case ErrorStatus.Error2:
                    ...
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to use an Enumeration, you could pass Exception directly: `public Exception errorStatus = null;` This allows HelperFunction to throw exception with `try { HelperFunction(); } catch (Exception ex) { errorStatus = ex; DialogResult = DialogResult.Abort; }` in your Shown event. `callback` could then process errorStatus if it is not null.

Comment: Thanks for finding out why this happens. But does this mean, that in standalone applications the message loop from the sub-forms are not processed but kind of redirected to the main window message loop?

The solution you provided might work (I'm sure it does) but I solved the problem by moving the try-catch block into the form. That was easier :-). And I think it is basically better design than before.

So as a rule of thumb I will take that **never try to pass exceptions from one form to another in C#**. Thanks all for the help.